# How to initialize a logger in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, logging

I have read the documentation on this [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) and the [class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/logger/rdoc/Logger.html). **I wish to create a logger  which take logging informations each day and after let's say a week, delete the oldest logging information automatically each time.**

```
logfile = File.open(RAILS_ROOT + '/log/'+ (Date.today << 1).to_s + '_custom.log', 'a')  #create log file
logfile.sync = true  #automatically flushes data to file
CUSTOM_LOGGER = CustomLogger.new(logfile, 'daily')  #constant accessible anywhere
```

Plus, I wish to create a custom logging, so for instance something that looks like this (format):

```
class MyLogger < Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp} : #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

So basically, I would like to have a better idea where to place everything correctly under which directory. For instance, where MyLogger should be logically placed... (anywhere? A helper? or under app/config/ ?

Is [that](http://ianma.wordpress.com/2009/04/08/custom-logging-in-ruby-on-rails/) a valid way to implement this?

**I made it by putting everything in config/initializers and creating a file named my_logger.rb. I'm still stuck at deleting/managing log files.**

Does the server handle that part with a log rotation ( I know there's something with logrotation from the linux OS)? Or Rails can handle that internally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Where should MyLogger be logically placed?

   Probably put it under /lib.  You can then require it from the initializer where you set the custom logger.
2. How can you periodically delete the oldest logging information?

   There are a countless ways you can do this and choosing will be based on your constraints.   You haven't spoken much about your constraints, so it's going to be hard to give you the just-right answer.  E.g. you could clean up old logs every time you add a new log entry, you could run a cron job, you could install some non-Rails software that does log rotation and other log maintenance, you could use Papertrail, if you use Heroku you could look up https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes.

   Remember Rails is designed more to handle requests and respond to them in the context of that request, than to run maintenance outside of the context of receiving a request.  You could do maintenance as a side-effect of every format_message request to MyLogger, checking for the oldest logging entry and if you find one older than a week, delete them.  You haven't given a constraint why you can't do this in-process, and if you're prototyping something early and portable, then this would get you going fast.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I agree with your first answer, this is the way I have done it. Secondly, I was thinking about going with logrotation from linux (since my server runs it) and find decent information on the net to implement it easily.